# Ionic start <Project> <Template> Freezes

Tags: javascript, node.js, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to start a new project in the ionic framework with the following command

```
ionic start MyFirstIonic blank
```

However, no matter what I try the command prompt just sits there and blinks and eventually goes unresponsive.
I had downloaded everything I needed to run an application about a month ago and everything seemed to work just fine. However, now when I try to create a new project it just freezes.

I have a school project I need to get done and this is really stressing me out. I have tried the following solutions but to no avail.

- Cleaning the cache
- uninstalling and reinstalling ionic and cordova
- uninstalling and reinstalling node
- installing an earlier version of node (V8.11)
- Going to my app roaming and deleting `npm` and `npm cache`

None of these proposed solutions I found online seem to work.

These are my current versions

[image: CLI output showing ionic -v shows 4.10.1]

Here is the infinite loop error:

[image: result of invoking ionic start - hanging at Starter template: blank]

If anyone has any ideas on how to get my programming environment up and running I would greatly appreciate it! I am already running behind on my assignments and really do not wish to fall even further behind.

Answer (score 1):

This is only a workaround, but I found this freezing quite a pain when running Ionic 4 apps in my laptop, whilst the commands usually works for my regular work machine.

try including the command `--no-interactive` when running ionic start.

**Format:**

```
ionic start {projectName} {template} --no-interactive
```

**Sample:**

```
ionic start test2 blank --no-interactive
```

This usually does the trick for me.

Comment: are there any other logs presented? or does it just freeze indefinitely?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Uninstalling the old CLI and installing the new CLI (with a different name) fixed the problem for me:

```
npm uninstall -g ionic 
npm install -g @ionic/cli
```